# How to combine AutoMapper 5.2 with SimpleInjector for WCF service hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, automapper, simple-injector

So far we've used the SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory in the SimpleInjector.Integration.Wcf for our WCF services.
This allowed us to avoid the typical "No parameterless constructor defined", when we have interfaces as parameters that SimpleInjector should resolve.

In the global.asax:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WcfOperationLifestyle();
container.Register<IOurBusinessService, OurBusinessService>();
container.Verify();
SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory.SetContainer(container);
```

To configure/register AutoMapper we would call some code to register it in the Global.asax, like so:

```
var cfg = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
cfg.CreateMap<SomeObject, SomeObjectDTO>();
Mapper.Initialize(cfg);
Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

However it seems that when our Web-Services are called directly with a net.tcp endpoint, there is sometimes no more AutoMapper registered. This seems to be the case as the code in Global.asax in Application_Start is never executed, when the WCF service is requested directly.

We currently try to derive from ServiceHostFactory and register both AutoMapper and SimpleInjector in our overridden CreateServiceHost method.
This however does give us again the "No parameterless constructor defined" error.

Do you have any solution or best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make the above scenario work was to derive from SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory and do the override there.

```
public class OurServiceHostFactory : SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        // ConfigInit is a static class with a simple check, to see if the configuration was already initialized
        // the same method ConfigInig.Configure() is also called in the Global.asax in Application_Start
        ConfigInit.Configure();
        return base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your configuration correct?

You can create the `Mapper` at startup and then inject it as a singleton dependency:

Create the `Mapper` ([code found here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Static-and-Instance-API)):

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfile<AppProfile>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
// or
IMapper mapper = new Mapper(config);
```

Register as singleton:

```
var container = new Container();

// Registrations
container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IMapper), mapper);
```

To inject:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    private readonly IMapper mapper;
    public MyClass(IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this will solve you "No parameterless constructor" issue, but this is a good way to handle the AutoMapper injection. If It does not solve the problem, let me know.

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see it could make sense to pass the IMapper to all constructors where needed. Currently we use the Mapper.Map<...>(...) directly. Maybe that is kind of an anti-pattern?

Comment: I think it makes sense to initialize the AutoMapper in SimpleInjector as you specified, but for it to work in the mentioned scenario it  seems to be required to inherit from SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory. Guess I'll mark my own as answer.

Comment: Yeah, it appears there was more to the issue. I do consider direct invocation a bit of an anti-pattern, but in all honestly it doesn't really matter. I wouldn't worry about refactoring unless you run into some integration issues down the line.